# Laravel 4 REST API join table

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, rest

I'm trying to make a REST API using laravel 4 and I'm trying to join 3 table to get the data but when I check the url in postman it shows html page that says

```
<title>Whoops! There was an error.</title>
```

but when i check it using sql query it returns 2 data.

Here is the UrlController

```
public function tayang($idKota)
{
    $tayang=DB::table('detiltayang')
    ->join('tayang','detiltayang.idTayang','=','tayang.idTayang')
    ->join('bioskop','tayang.idBioskop','=','bioskop.idBioskop')
    ->join('film','tayang.idFilm','=','film.idFilm')
    ->where('bioskop.idKota','=',$idKota);

    return Response::json($tayang);
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('api/{idKota}/tayang','UrlController@tayang')
```

Can anyone tell me how to join table in rest api? thanks in advance

Comment: Turn debugging on and see what the actual error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `->get()`

```
public function tayang($idKota)
{
    $tayang=DB::table('detiltayang')
    ->join('tayang','detiltayang.idTayang','=','tayang.idTayang')
    ->join('bioskop','tayang.idBioskop','=','bioskop.idBioskop')
    ->join('film','tayang.idFilm','=','film.idFilm')
    ->where('bioskop.idKota','=',$idKota)->get();

    return Response::json($tayang);
}
```

Also check that you have `use DB;`